# Popup message: Doesn't work with jquery 1.7

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a problem with version of jQuery. The website I use, uses version 1.7 of jQuery. However, I have a script that runs on version 1.4.
Site version: 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Script version: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Content script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openOffersDialog() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#boxpopup').css('display','block');
        $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'30%'},500);
    });
}

// PROBLEM WITH THIS PART (cant close popup):
function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) {
    $(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#boxpopup').css('position','absolute');
            $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
                $('#boxpopup').css('position','fixed');
                $('#boxpopup').css('left','100%');
                $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Are they used some old features jquery?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your `closeOffersDialog()` function is called from a button click or some such. If it is, wrapping the function contents inside the `DOMReady` listener is pointless:

Try this:

```
function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) 
{    
    $('#boxpopup').css('position','absolute');
    $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
        $('#boxpopup').css('position','fixed');
        $('#boxpopup').css('left','100%');
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
     });
}
```